# What is equivalent of opencv comaparision operator in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-comparison

Following are the ways of doing comparison in C++ and java

C++ 
`image < 100`

Java

```
Core.compare(image, 100, mask, Core.CMP_LE);
```

How this can be done in python?

Comment: It is trivial, `cv2.compare(img, 100, cv2.CMP_LT)`

Comment: Thank you yangjie. can you please provide the url of opencv 3 api reference for python bindings.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare